# Regex to match "[any single digit number]" and ":any four digit number/"

Tags: regex, vbscript

I require the regex to match the following pattern in *vbscript*

**[any single digit number]** and **:any four digit number/**

That is, **a open square bracket followed by a single digit number followed by a close square bracket** or **a colon followed by four digit number followed by a slash**

I've tried the following pattern which select just a single digit also

```
[\[]*([:]*([0-9]{1,4})[/]*)[]]*
```

Thanks in advance,
Madhan

Comment: Post your attempt please.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: "[\[]*([:]*([0-9]{1,4})[/]*)[]]*"

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
(\[\d\]|\:\d{4}\/)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/RMIzW9HzV7)

Comment: No need to escape colon and slash.

Comment: Some regex engine do not accept some characters directly, so it is a good practice to escape them always.

Comment: The VBScript engine does accept unescaped colons and slashes. I usually recommend against making a regular expression more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(\[\d\]|:\d{4}/)
```